# Upload bar like gmail for multiple files in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I need the multiple file upload functionalities like as shown below in the mean js project:
[image]

I have used angular file uploader to implement this functionality from [here](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload):

I have tried with progress properties from above link but unable to get exact output.
Please suggest me the appropriate links to implement.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: We have used progress feature of uploader

Comment: Please update your question with more details .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `queue` and `progress` properties of angular uploader for more details check Module API details from [here](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API).

For example in the `uploader.queue` contains the queue of file items, you just need to iterate it and get the progress in percentage like `item.progress`.

For just reference use following code

```
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.uploader.queue">
                    <td><strong>{{ item.file.name }}</strong></td>
                    <td nowrap>{{ item.file.size/1024/1024|number:2 }} MB</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" ng-style="{ 'width': item.progress + '%' }">{{item.progress}}%</div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <span ng-show="item.isSuccess"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
                        <span ng-show="item.isCancel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i></span>
                        <span ng-click="item.remove()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Hope this will help you !!